# Filtering nested views in DRF, how to implement?

Tags: django-rest-framework

There is a product serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field="name", read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields=(
        'id',
        'name',
        'category', 
        'subcategory',
        'manufacturer',
        'get_absolute_url',
        'description',
        'price',
        'get_image',
        'get_thumbnail'
    )
```

As well as a category serializer that generates a nested representation of the products associated with this category:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = (
        'id',
        'name',
        'get_absolute_url',
        'products'
    )
```

Sample Data:

```
 [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Notebook",
        "get_absolute_url": "/notebooks/",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "HP for work",
                "category": "Notebook",
                "subcategory": "Working",
                "manufacturer": "HP",
                "get_absolute_url": "/notebooks/hp_2000/",
                "description": "desc",
                "price": "25000.00",
                "get_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/slidebar-image1.jpg",
                "get_thumbnail": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/uploads/slidebar-image1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Acer for game",
                "category": "Notebook",
                "subcategory": "Gamers",
                "manufacturer": "Acer",
                "get_absolute_url": "/notebooks/acer_for_game/",
                "description": "Desc",
                "price": "50000.00",
                "get_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/AcerAspire_6m9A45R.jpg",
                "get_thumbnail": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/uploads/AcerAspire_6m9A45R.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I can also display filtered products in the URL using query parameters, for example, by subcategory:

```
url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/query-product/?sub=Gamers:

[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Acer for game",
    "category": "Notebook",
    "subcategory": "Gamers",
    "manufacturer": "Acer",
    "get_absolute_url": "/notebooks/acer_for_game/",
    "description": "Desc",
    "price": "50000.00",
    "get_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/AcerAspire_6m9A45R.jpg",
    "get_thumbnail": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/uploads/AcerAspire_6m9A45R.jpg"
}
```

]

This is where the product is filtered:

```
class ProductQueryList(generics.ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = ProductSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = Product.objects.all()
       subcategory_name = self.request.query_params.get('sub')
       if subcategory_name is not None:
           queryset = queryset.filter(subcategory = subcategory_name)
       return queryset
```

I'm stuck at the moment with filtering for categories.  Here I either pass a `queryset` containing a specific category, or pass the filtered products associated with this category to the same `queryset`:

```
class CategoryDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
def get_queryset(self):
    category = self.kwargs['category_slug']
    # queryset = Category.objects.get(slug=category)
    # subcategory_name = self.request.query_params.get('sub')
    # # if subcategory_name is not None:
    #     queryset = queryset.products.filter(subcategory = subcategory_name)
    return Category.objects.filter(slug=category)
```

Is there any way to pass something like `queryset.products` to the nested products list? Those somehow pass the category to the `queryset`, and override the products nested in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object here to achieve the nested filtering, something like this:

```
class CategoryDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.kwargs['category_slug']
        queryset = Category.objects.get(slug=category)
        
        subcategory_name = self.request.query_params.get('sub')
        if subcategory_name is not None:
            prefetch_filtered_products = Prefetch(
              'products', 
              Product.objects.filter(subcategory=subcategory_name)
            )
            return queryset.prefetch_related(prefetch_filtered_products)
        return queryset.prefetch_related('products')
```

This should also save you from making extra queries to the database.